# Add a string to JQuery result

Tags: jquery

I am new to JQuery and still battling a learning curve.

I am trying to figure out how to add a `$` to the result of this function.

I tried many different combinations and searched high and low trying to figure it out.

Any help or advice would be fantastic.

```
$('#qty1, #unit1').change(function(){
    var qty1 = parseFloat($('#qty1').val()) || 0;
    var unit1 = parseFloat($('#unit1').val()) || 0;

    $('#totalt1').val((qty1 * unit1).toFixed(2));    
});
```

Comment: `$('#totalt1').val('$' + (qty1 * unit1).toFixed(2));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just concatenate a string:

```
$('#totalt1').val('$' + (qty1 * unit1).toFixed(2));
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add the `$` before it like so.

```
$('#qty1, #unit1').change(function(){
    var qty1 = parseFloat($('#qty1').val()) || 0;
    var unit1 = parseFloat($('#unit1').val()) || 0;

    $('#totalt1').val("$" + (qty1 * unit1).toFixed(2));    
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kzu4r14o/